iOS simulators are not visible in Visual Studio MAC
I am not able to configure iOS simulators into Visual Studio 2022 MAC. I have downloaded Latest versions of Xcode (version - 15.3) and the Visual Studio MAC (version - 17.6.11). Also I am using Sonoma 14.4.1 macOS. I have set the Apple SDK location as Xcode applications location as shown below

Still, I am not able to see iOS simulators in Visual Studio MAC. Please help me to resolve this issue.

are the iOS simulators installed in XCode?

I think this probably has to do with compatibility, is the latest version of Visual studio compatible with the latest version of XCode?

@Jason Yes I have installed iOS simulators in Xcode.

@FreakyAli As I have checked the compatibility, the visual studio and Xcode which I am using are compatible.

Give me your current versions of both

MAC Version - Sonoma 14.4.1, Visual Studio MAC Version - 17.6.11, Xcode Version - 15.3

Yup just as I thought, you need XCode 15.2, 15.3 is not supported yet...

I tried with Xcode versions 15, 15.2 and 15.3 but still its not working.

When you downloaded 15.2 did you make sure VS was using the correct version of XCode, check this bug https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21057

Once Xcode is installed, you need to start xcode, it will ask to download and install iOS 17.4. Once that is done, quit and start Visual Studio again, and it should show all the Simulators.
If it still doens't, you need to go to Xcode settings and select command-line tools again, it should work then. This happens many times as when you have multiple versions of Xcode or download different versions, wrong command-line tools get selected or sometimes it doesn't get selected, even it is shows selected.
Just selecting the command-line tools fixes the problem.

I tried changing command-line and selecting it again. Then quit visual studio and Xcode but still issue persist. Is there any issue with Visual Studio 2022 MAC with MAUI ?

Will you please let me know which workloads I have to install to get the iOS simulators into Visual Studio 2022 MAC for MAUI project ?

which dotnet version are you working on? .net6/7/8?
Visual Studio by default won't support net8 if you are using that.

maui, maui-ios and maui-android are the important workloads that you need for sure.
You can check by running
dotnet workload list
You can install the workloads with
dotnet workload install maui
dotnet workload install maui-ios
dotnet workload install maui-android

If you are working on .NET8, the goto Visual Studio Preferences -> Other -> Preview Features -> Check Use the .NET8 SDK and then restart Visual Studio.

One more additional info, .NET8 apps are currently crashing on latest iOS. You need to install iOS 17.2 Simulators. iOS 17.2 works fine with .NET8.

By installing the workloads sorted the issue. Thanks you so much Preetanshu Mishra.

I experienced missing simulators in VS Code after XCode updated. Fixed it by doing the following:

Install latest XCode

Install XCode Command Line Tools (same version as xcode)

Install the latest Simulators

Reboot

Open XCode, go to Settings -> Locations and make sure the Command Lines Tools is set to the latest version

install the workloads again:
sudo dotnet workload install maui
sudo dotnet workload install maui-ios
sudo dotnet workload install maui-android


